# Variable assignement or if/else not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have this problem when I assign a variable and/or the if/else.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100 + 1)
       document.write(y)
    if (y>=1 && y<50){
       document.write("50 or smaller")
    }else{
       document.write("51 or bigger")
    }
</script>
```

I starting out in HTML and JS, so any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What is not working? What happens? Did you get any errors?

Comment: and the problem is.....

Comment: The parentheses seem unbalanced in the first line. Three opening, only two closing.

Comment: Nothing is being output. It's just a blank white screen when I run and I saved.

Comment: You should see a syntax error in the Javascript console (ALWAYS keep that one open when doing JS development)

Comment: as @Thilo has mentioned you have a syntax error on the first statement which javascript probably won't notify you. Also, i know javascript lets you omit semi-colons but please put them in.

Comment: as you're starting out so may be you don't know this but ideally JavaScript code execution stops when it encounters an error.
and as @Thilo mentioned you have a syntax error on your first line

Answer (score 2):

Add `;`

```
var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1); // get a random number
document.write(y);// print it
if (y>=1 && y<=50){
   document.write("50 or smaller");
}else{
   document.write("51 or bigger");
}
```

Comment: @Thilo no need for it, removed.

Comment: @George you can omit ; but you end up with hidden syntax errors like the original code, I just separated the statements and the code was fixed.